# How to select from multiple prefabs for a player

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I'm making a game online. I have 12 character prefabs that I select from a menu and the selection is saved in SQL. For multiplayer I use Alteruna, but there players can only use 1 prefab. How to solve this and make it spawn the prefab that was selected in the menu?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is either change the model on an already spawned avatar.
Alternatively, you can have multiple versions of your player under your avatar and enable the relevant one.